# Error deleting rows from mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm having trouble deleting rows from the database. I try to bind the parameter (id) according to which a row has to be deleted. It returns success message that the row has been deleted but the row is not actually deleted from the database.
Here's the code where I'm calling the delete script using ajax:

```
<script>
    $("#del").click(function(){
        var id;
        $("input:checked").each(function(){
            id=$(this).parent().parent().children(".id").html();
        });
        var datastring=JSON.stringify(id);
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'delete.php',
            data: {data:datastring},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the delete script (delete.php)

```
if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
    $id=$_POST["data"];
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","products");
    if($db)
    {
        $query=mysqli_prepare($db,"DELETE FROM product_info WHERE prod_id=?");
        $query->bind_param('i',$id);
        $result=$query->execute(array($id));
        if($result)
            echo "Deleted successfully";
        else
            echo "Error in deletion of product";
        $query->close();
    }
    else
        echo "Error Connecting to DB";
}
else
    echo "POST not set";
```

The statement "Deleted successfully" is echoed back and alerted but the row is not actually deleted from the database. If i omit the bind_param part and directly specify the id in the query, then the record is deleted.
Help!

Comment: Which value contains `id` in your jQuery function?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($id)` after getting it from the `$_POST['data']` to check if it's in a format you need for the binding. But from the looks of it you're trying to convert an array into JSON and in that case you can't directly use it with an `=` operator, you'll need to render an `IN` condition

Comment: Even after using the IN condition in the query, the result is the same @fejese

Comment: id is the id of a row which can be selected from the table based on which checkbox is checked...
it is stored in the variable id in jQuery @S.Pols

Comment: @NoN01, do a `var_dump($id)` and include the output it in the question

Comment: Jup, what @fejese said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue has been resolved. The statement causing the problem was this one:

```
var datastring=JSON.stringify(id);
```

Instead, I did this in the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'delete.php',
            data: {data:id},  //instead of sending datastring, I sent the id directly
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
  });
```